# How Do You Figure Out What the Date Format Is For a Given NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdateformatter

Hey StackOverflow People,

I have a date timestamp NSString with the following value that I get from a backend server:

```
NSString *date = @"2014-01-27T21:06:59.000-05:00";
```

I can't for the life of me figure out what the date format is for the string above and have been trying to use a `NSDateFormatter` object with the two following date formats (that have both returned me `nil`):

Format 1: `@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.000-05:00";`

Format 2: `@"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS-SS:SS";`

My question is: how the heck do you use an already given string to determine what date format you're working with?

Comment: The -05.00 is probably an offset from UTC, ie time zone information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it works:

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
```

The -05:00 is the Timezone, you need to use `ZZZZZ` for that.

Also, because `T` is not part of the date, you need to scape it, use `'T'` for that.

Notice the `HH` instead of `hh`.

Find all the formatters with examples here:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

About your question of how to know the format, you have to guess it based on what you see, or ask the person providing that date.

Comment: Actually, for a timezone in the format `-##:##` you want to use `ZZZZZ`, not `v`.

Comment: Also, use http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns to see the current format specifiers. That is the official reference.

Comment: According to the docs `v` is meant for timezones with a format such as `PT`. See the docs you linked to.

Comment: All of you guys are awesome. I didn't know how to escape characters in a format string template. Thank you so much for this information! I was able to format it successfully!